# Problems with Python Flask using TLS

Tags: python, ssl, flask

Im a bit struggling with using TLS with python flask

I've generate the certificate with that line:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

In my python code I used this code:

```
import ssl 
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')

app = Flask(__name__)

...
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(app.run(ssl_context=context))
```

The exact same code worked for me yesterday but today it just doesnt work...
it does look like the flask server is running with HTTPS though:
[image]

But when Im trying to access the website the browser just doesnt let me.

any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

For a local SSL certificate to work, you won't just need the certificate and key. You'll also need to have it signed by a local Certificate Authority (CA) and add it to your system which differed depending on your OS

In your case, you need to install the `cert.pem` file generated

Since your screenshot showed that you use Windows, you could try to add it to your system by following [this article](https://babelway.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360027367853-HOW-TO-CREATE-SELF-SIGNED-SSL-CERTIFICATES-IN-WINDOWS-10)

Once the certificate is installed, the browsers will show you the error but allow you to proceed

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: thank you! I’ll try to do that when i’ll be back at home!